# How to attach a PDF to an email sent from an express app

Tags: node.js, email, express, pdf, mandrill

I am trying to send an email with a PDF attachment, but the PDF cannot be opened. (How can I load a PDF from the filesystem and include that in an email that is sent from an express app?)

**This is what I have now:** I load the PDF from the filesystm like this: `var pdfAttach = fs.readFileSync('./pdfs/test.pdf', 'binary');` and include it in the object that is sent to Mandrill like this:

```
{
...
attachments:
  [{content: pdfAttach,
    name: "testing.pdf",
    type: "application/pdf"
  }],
...
}
```

The recipient gets an email with an PDF file that he cannot open. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look to Mandrill's Messages API [here](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.nodejs.html), you will see that the content of the attachment must be a base64 encoded string. so the code would be:

```
var pdfAttach = fs.readFileSync('./pdfs/test.pdf');
...
attachments:
  [{content: pdfAttach.toString('base64'),
    name: "testing.pdf",
    type: "application/pdf"
}],
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thank you